# Resize a thumbnail into a video

Tags: html

I'd like resize my poster into video shorter than video size; 320w/240h.

```
<div class="greetings-gp text-center">
<video width="320" height="240" poster="img/Logo_GP.png" controls>
   <source src="video/Welcome%20Partners!%20(1).mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
   </source>
</video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code. It solved the issue in all latest version of the browser.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="video/mp4; charset=utf-8" />

</head>

<body>

<div class="greetings-gp text-center">

<video width="320" height="240" poster="flower.png" controls>
   <source src="Pyramids - 1565.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
   <source src="Red - 14840.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </source>
</video>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```